# Moving from Angularjs to Blazor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, webassembly

I am going to use blazor in my .net app. Could any one who use it face any problem where he stuck in some point because blazor missing some basic feature somehow .**Is it safe to start use it in production?**
And i know that the web assembly files for blazor cached in browser, So is there a way to update the cached file with modified one like versioning in JS file for example .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended by the Blazor team to use Blazor WebAssembly in production.  Blazor WebAssembly is in its preview phase now, and it would be production ready around May 2020. However, you can use Blazor Server App which is production enabled and supported by Microsoft, as a temporary solution or a permanent one, as you can switch from one flavor of blazor to another relatively very easily. I myself moved from Angular to Blazor, at the time Asp.Net Core bloggers were shamelessly warning their readers  that Blazor is actually another Silverlight. But I made a decision to move and I do not regret it. I feel at home with Microsoft technologies, and using Blazor is real fun. Don't hesitate to move...you won't regret it.

Blazor has a great future and a bright one...

I actually posted this as a comment, but it was too long...

Comment: what is the risk of use unsupported for production tech?@enet

Answer (score 1):

Blazor supports server and client hosting models.

- Server hosting(called Blazor Server) is just classic ASP.NET with razor templating which was released in 2011, is mature and Microsoft has approved it for production use, so you can use it in production.
- Client hosting(called Blazor WebAssembly) is very new and is one of the first frameworks built on top of WebAssembly running inside the browser, said to be ready for production use around May 2020, so better to wait on this one - but looks very promising indeed, providing a path for C# developers to do full stack web development.

Regarding clearing of cache, browsers provide Web APIs to do it. E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete